# How in rails 4.1 enum prescribe in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

How in rails 4.1 enum prescribe in migration something like this?

```
class CreateFriendsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friends_users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :friend_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :status, [:active, :deactive]
    end
  end
end
```

this is join table for user and user

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends,
:class_name => "User",
:foreign_key => "user_id",
:association_foreign_key => "friend_id",
:join_table => "friends_users",
:after_add => :add_friend,
:after_remove => :remove_friend
```